# Jenkins - SonarQube: Angular Test coverage karma alternative without browser

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to find an alternative to generate a coverage report for an angular project with jenkins and karma, the problem comes because it is not allowed to install at least a headless browser in the CI servers of the company so Jenkins fails the job due no browser found.

I know there are a lot of frameworks for testing but I want to ask you for the best alternative for coverage report for sonarqube without browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use Jest for pipelines where you cannot install a browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).